# Android honeycomb fast scrollbar inside the ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-scrollbar

I have a ListView with several elements, so I need to use a fast scrollbar from the Android Honeycomb API. I want the fast scrollbar to be on the left side of the list, for that I'm doing `getListView().setVerticalScrollbarPosition(ListView.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);`

The problem is that the fast scrollbar is actually inside the list, on the left side of it, but I want the scrollbar to be outside the list, on the left of it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think its possible to make a part of the view to appear outside of its own dimensions (border) ..
did you tried solving your specific problem using padding ?

Comment: Thanks, padding solved the issue. I don't know how I didn't think about that before, too early in the morning I guess :)